# Data aggregation over rows while averaging over one column

Tags: python, database, pandas, aggregation

I have a large dataset, consisting of 3 million rows. I want to aggregate every five rows of data while averaging over the values in one column and return a new table.

I am very much new with coding, so I appreciate any help! I already imported my dataset using pandas.

This is what I have in terms of my data:

```
    Q   A   B
0   NAME1   TIME1   1
1   NAME1   TIME2   5
2   NAME1   TIM3    8
3   NAME1   TIME4   9
4   NAME1   TIME5   45
0   NAME2   TIME11  100
1   NAME2   TIME22  200
2   NAME2   TIME33  300
3   NAME2   TIME44  400
4   NAME2   TIME55  500
```

and this is what I wan to get out of this code:

```
    X   Y   B
NAME1   TIME1   TIME5   AVE(1,5,8,9,45)
NAME2   TIME11  TIME55  AVE(100,200,300,400,500)
```

Comment: `df.groupby('Q').agg({'A':['first','last'],'B':'mean'})
`?

Comment: Does `Q`column keep tracks of the 5 row groups?

Comment: No, it does not!